# Aws Glue: AnalysisException: Column value#1260 are ambiguous

Tags: pyspark, etl, aws-glue, parquet

I am trying to join two data frames in aws glue v4.0 with multiple conditions. Getting below error. The below code worked on v2.0

Here is join that i am performing

```
p_df = p_df.alias("p").join(c_map.alias("m"), (p_df.source == c_map.id) & (p_df.p_code == c_map.p_code) & (c_map.id == 1), "left").select("p.*", F.when(c_map.value.isNull(),lit('NA')).otherwise(c_map.value).alias("c_type"))
    
    
p_df = p_df.alias("p").join(c_map.alias("m"), ( p_df.d_type == c_map.id) & (p_df.p_code == c_map.p_code) & (c_map.id== 2), "left").select("p.*", F.when(c_map.value.isNull(),lit('NA')).otherwise(c_map.value).alias("c_cat"))
```

Tried to drop columns and updated resultant data frame. Its not working.
Anyone can help over here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you `print(c_map.columns)`?

Comment: @Emma i did that, it print duplicate columns having 3 columns as duplicates

Comment: okay. In that case, you should resolve the duplicates in upstream.